# initialize/create a vector in a class c++

Tags: c++, vector

I just started learning C++ using "Programming principles and practice using C++", and I do not understand something regarding the initialization/creation of a vector in a class. Take the following code as an example:

```
class A{
public:
    vector<int>a1{6,6,6,6,6,6};
    vector<int>a2(int a, int b);
    //some code here
}
```

For the first vector a1 I declared with specifying all the elements in it. It is compiled successfully with a message "trivially range-checked vector" when I move my cursor over a1. What does the message mean?

For the second vector a2 I declared with two int variables a and b as the size and value of the vector respectively. It is compiled successfully with a message "function definition 'a2' not found" when I move my cursor over a2. Why does the compiler treat a2 as a function instead of a vector? And the message seems like an error, but why does it compile successfully anyway?

Comment: look at lambda in c++11

Comment: "Why does the compiler treat a2 as a function instead of a vector?" - because that's function declaration syntax, the same as `int main(int a, char **b)`.

Comment: then why does the declaration of "function" a2 not found? since it is declared as `vector<int>a2(int a, int b);`?

Comment: @qsmy It says "*definition* not found". The distinction between declarations and definitions is important (and, unfortunately, not always obvious). Judging by the table of contents, chapter 8 should be relevant.

Comment: If you never use a function that has been declared but not defined, there will be no compilation problems.

Comment: @molbdnilo oh ok, thanks I got it now.

Comment: Lastly, don't rely too much on your IDE's interactive messages – C++ is hard to interpret "on the fly". Treat them as possibly wrong hints, not as facts.

Comment: @molbdnilo "hard to interpret 'on the fly'" as in the compiler has difficulties in understanding the code while running the programme? Is this what you mean?

Comment: @qsmy I mean "on the fly" as in "while you're writing it". The interactive feedback is usually not provided by the actual compiler. (And I didn't mean "interpret" as in "execute in an interpreter".)

Comment: @molbdnilo ok thanks a lot!